# Nilpotent torsion-free Groups with a fixed Soluble length

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solvable-groups, nilpotence

Let $s$ be a natural number. Is it possible to find, for each $n$ natural number greater than some arbitrary constant, a torsion-free group whose nilpotency class is $n$ and soluble length is $s$?

Comment: No, because $s$ and $n$ are constrained by $n\geq 2^{s-1}$.

Comment: I've edited the question. I'm interested in an answer with $n$ grower than some fixed integer.

Comment: Pardon! I meant ``greater than''.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the semidirect product $G_n$ of ${\mathbb Z}^n$ generated by $x_1,\ldots,x_n$, with an infinite cyclic group $\langle y \rangle$, where $x_i^y=x_ix_{i+1}$ for $i<n$ and $x_n^y=x_n$. Then $G_n$ is nilpotent of class $n-1$ and solvable of length $2$.

For each $s>2$, let $H_s$ be a fixed torsion-free nilpotent group of solvable length $s$. Then $G_{n+1} \times H_s$ satisfies your conditions whenever $n$ is at least the nilpotency class of $H_s$.

Comment: Could you also provide a generic example of a torsion-free nilpotent group of fixed solvable length?

Comment: Not exactly. The solubility length of the upper unitriangular integer $n \times n$ matrices increases unboundedly with $n$, but I don't know the exact formula. I think a free nilpotent group with enough generators (at least $3$?) and class $2^{s-1}$ has solubility length $s$. I expect somebody knows!

Comment: Let $G$ be a group of soluble length $s$ and nilpotent class $n$. Then let $[G\times G]\mathbb{Z}$ where $\mathbb{Z}$ act on $G\times G$ as in your example. I think this has solubility length $s+1$ and it is nilpotent of class $2\cdot n$. What do you say?